# Add XML String as Node to Existing XML

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml/mathml fragment in string like `<msup><mn>2</mn><mn>6</mn></msup><mo>+</mo><msup><mn>2</mn><mn>7</mn></msup>`

I want to replace an existing xml node with this string. I tried

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuild = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuild.parse(is); //is ==> Inputstream
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new Namespace());
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xPath); //xPath ==>XPath of parent node where the above is to be appended
    Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    if (node.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName().equals("mml:math")) {
        node.removeChild((node.getChildNodes().item(0)));
        Element s= doc.createElement("mml:math");
        s.setNodeValue("<msup><mn>2</mn><mn>6</mn></msup><mo>+</mo><msup><mn>2</mn><mn>7</mn></msup>");
        node.appendChild(s);
    }
```

Comment: So what happened with the code you tried?

Comment: XML didn't get updated....

Comment: If you provide source xml, it would be easy to answer your question

Comment: @ssanrao, xml is pretty big...

Comment: @JonSkeet replied to my post :)

Comment: You still haven't said what happened with your original code though, which means the question/answer pair isn't terribly useful.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Previous child nodes were removed successfully but new node was not inserted. I was getting an empty mathml node(`<mml:math/>`)

Comment: So you should show that *in your question*, ideally with a [mcve] rather than just snippets. Ideally, the question would take the form: 1) Input; 2) Code (complete console app); 3) Expected output; 4) Actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `s.setNodeValue()`, I used `s.setTextContent()` which fixed my problem.